# Any way to 'hack' Internet Explorer 10 to display border-image?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I've only recently come to [realise that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#border_and_layout) Internet Explorer 10 doesn't support the CSS border-image property at all, not even using a vendor-prefix.

My normal go-to solution would be to use CSS3 PIE, however that's in the rather unique position of being unable to do a whole lot to help given that Microsoft have opted to depreciate support for .htc behaviours in IE10.  There's a discussion about this on their forums [here](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1913).

It seems possible that there might be a work-around by building a custom JS version of CSS3 PIE but I'm loath to take the performance-hit.

Is there any other way that anybody has discovered to convince IE10 to support border-image (as it really should!).

Comment: 99% sure you'll either have to script it or just mark it out the gate as up as a 9x9 grid with background images. `border-image` is just a fancy replacement for the 9x9 grid anyway ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE10 doesn't *completely* remove support for HTC behaviors. You can still use them if you [force IE10 to emulate IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you can do by adding the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

This would let you use CSS3 PIE's HTC behaviors again, but it would also prevent you from using other new features introduced in IE10. It's a tradeoff, but one that would allow your site to appear as intended in IE10 until such time as a better `border-image` polyfill is available.

Comment: Thank you, I've not had chance to investigate this fully, and suspect I'll simply take the 'graceful degradation' approach on this one for the time-being.  Your suggestion certainly makes the most sense if border-image is essential.

It's a shame that even with Microsoft's latest browser there are still significant compromises compared to the competition.  Says a lot that in this instance their previous browser is better!